# How to drop user@% on the MySQL CLI?

Tags: mysql, command-line

How to drop `'user'@'%'` on the MySQL CLI using the `mysql -e` command?

```
mysql -uroot  -p -e "'myuser'@'%'";
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to surround the `%` character with single quotes

```
DROP USER user@'%';
```

or put the user in single quotes as well

```
DROP USER 'user'@'%';
```

From the CLI, you would run something like this

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="DROP USER 'user'@'%'"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"
```

An alternative method would be delete it from `mysql.user`

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="DELETE FROM mysql.user"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE user='user'"
SQL="${SQL} AND host='%';"
SQL="${SQL} FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"
```